# How can I create a tightly packed uniform buffer of unsigned bytes?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Basically the title. This is an array that contains millions of numbers, so I want to minimize the space it takes up on the graphics card. Unfortunately, arrays in the std140 layout have a base alignment of 16 bytes, and GLSL doesn't have a built-in `unsigned char` type, so I'm not sure how I can do this efficiently.

Comment: The question still lacks details, for example the size of your data, the access pattern etc. GPUs do support 8bit integer types natively via texures and image objects. Apart from that, you could pack the stuff into a linear SSBO via an array of `uint`s.

Comment: Normally, array alignment specifies that the first element in the array will be on a 16 byte boundary, not that it's elements will each start on a 16 byte boundary.

Comment: @jwdonahue: not in OpenGL with the `sdt140` layout. But later versions support SSBOs with the `std430` layout, that differs in this very point.

Comment: Could you just pack four bytes per integer and decode each byte in your shader? The alignment for integers will be 4 so it should pack correctly.

Comment: @wcochran no, the alignment for each array element is a multiple of16 bytes in `std140` layout no matter the exact type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLSL does not have a type equivalent to a byte. But since all of its types are composed of a specific number of bytes, you can just extract the byte you need from a larger type. Such as `uint`, which is required to be 32-bits in size.

And of course, endian-ness is going to be a problem. The endian of a GPU is stated to match that of the CPU that feeds it. But you have to take that into account when you go to fetch a byte from a specific `uint`.

Of course, `std140` layout won't let you create a tightly packed array of `uint`. So don't; create a tightly packed array of `uvec4`. That's 4 integers.

So to fetch a specific unsigned byte from such a UBO, you have to do this:

```
layout(binding = #, std140) uniform BlockName
{
  uvec4 byte_array[NUM_BYTES / 16]; //NUM_BYTES must be a multiple of 16.
};

uint get_byte(uint byte_ix)
{
  uint byte_in_uint = byte_ix % 4;
  uint uint_in_vec = (byte_ix / 4) % 4;
  uint vec_ix = byte_ix / 16;

  uint bytes = byte_array[vec_ix][uint_in_vec];
  return (bytes >> ((4 - byte_in_uint) * 8)) && 0xFF; //Little-endian. For Big-endian, remove the "4 -" part.
}
```

That being said:

> This is an array that contains millions of numbers

Well, most cards won't allow you to access millions of anything though a single uniform block. The limit for uniform block size is only guaranteed to be at least 16KB, with sizes commonly seen around 64KB. Hardly "millions" of anything. The buffer object itself can hold whatever you can get the system to allocate, but any particular `glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ...)` call must be limited to the uniform block size.

If you need a single shader to potentially access more data, then you're going to have to use an SSBO or a buffer texture.